# Delete javascript function at position in file

Tags: javascript

I would like to delete a function form javascript at a position in a js source file, and re-write the file without it, so...

I have used a code analysis tool to get the position of the target function for deletion as line 5, column 0, in `myfile.js`

```
1 function keepme(x) {
2   return x + ' is ok';
3 }
4 
5 function delme(y) {
6   return y + ' oh why';
7 }
8 
9 /* code continues here */
```

I want to now use some kind of parser I guess in order to remove the function `delme` from the file.

I have looked at UglifyJS's build in parser, and treewalker, but seems to report the position of `function delme(y)`, not the whole function, so can't figure out how to find end point of function definition.

---

### For posterity...

```
var recast = require("recast");
var fs = require("fs");
var code = fs.readFileSync("billymoon.js").toString();

function stripByPosition(code, line, col) {
  
  var ast = recast.parse(code);

    recast.visit(ast, {
        visitFunctionDeclaration: function(path) {
            if (path.node.loc.start.line === line && path.node.loc.start.column === col) {
                path.prune();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

  return recast.print(ast).code;

}

console.log(stripByPosition(code, 5, 0));
console.log(stripByPosition(code, 1, 0));
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to premanently delete contents from the file, or simply during execution (temporary removal)?

Comment: Parse the file line by line and count the curly braces. Increment a counter on "{" and decrement on "}". When you reach 0, you will have parsed the whole function.

Comment: Closure Compiler can remove unused functions, if that what you mean

Comment: @JeffNoel I want to parse a js file on file system, then rewrite it with function removed - not during execution, but as static code analysis tool.

Comment: I would say using Matt R's idea slightly adapted could do it.
If you go through the file until you find  the string `"function delme("` you know you are at the beggining of the function. Then you simply start counting braces from the first opening one until you hit the closing one and remove the whole function this way (That's pure speculation, I have only used JavaScript in a web-based environment/browser). This will work assuming the file contains valid code.

Comment: @JeffNoel I think it must be done in a parser, otherwise there could be oddly matched brackets in strings, regex, or comments.

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere with uglify's tree walker - I must have been looking at the wrong function, now I can find a start/end pos on the node... `node.end.line` and `node.end.col`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you would like to use [the recast tool](https://github.com/benjamn/recast/) for this. Here's an example.

```
var recast = require("recast");
var fs = require("fs");
var code = fs.readFileSync("billymoon.js").toString();
var ast = recast.parse(code);

recast.visit(ast, {
  visitFunctionDeclaration: function (path) {
    var start = path.node.loc.start;
    if (start.line === 5 && start.column === 0) {
      path.prune();
    }
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(recast.print(ast).code);
```

Comment: looks interesting, but would need to identify function by line/col in source, as that is what I have from parser. Function might be anonymous function, or there could be two functions with the same name etc... I had a look through recast docs, and looks great - but did not see how to identify code from line/col

Comment: Having looked into it a bit more, looks like recast does report location of nodes in terms of line/col in it's `loc` property. Just need to use that to detect if it is correct function I guess...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I misread your question. You can replace the condition with `path.node.loc.start.line === 5`. And I should do that too.